# Sorting an array containing text with spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array containing strings. Each value typically has the following structure:
[registration number][ ][account number][, ][account name]

But in rare cases a value does not have the first 4 reg.numbers +  a space.

This is an example of an array:

```
var accounts = ["1111 12345678, Account1", 
              "2222 12345678, Account2", 
              "11345678, Account3", 
              "12345678, Account4", 
              "3333 12345678, Account5"];
```

I can sort accounts by using accounts.sort(), and that works almost fine. BUT I would like to have the values sorted AND have the values without reg.no appear last in the sorted array (still sorted alpabetically).

So sorting the accounts array should result in this list:

```
1111 12345678, Account1
2222 12345678, Account2
3333 12345678, Account5
11345678, Account3
12345678, Account4
```

Any good suggestion to this?

Comment: Are the numbers a fixed number of digits? If so, I would split the string into two strings, check the length of the first string, and create two arrays. One with, one without, the first four digits. Sort both, then concat. Sounds like a lot of work, but shouldn't change your time complexity if done right.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) accepts a function which defines how two elements should be sorted. Give it a shot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You culd check for leading numbers and sort this numbers to top.

```js
const hasLeading = s => /^\S+\s\S+\s\S+$/.test(s);

var accounts = ["1111 12345678, Account1", "2222 12345678, Account2", "11345678, Account3", "12345678, Account4", "3333 12345678, Account5"];

accounts.sort((a, b) => hasLeading(b) - hasLeading(a) || a > b || -(a < b));

console.log(accounts);
```

Comment: Excellent and shortest answer. Can you please explain the necessity of `a > b` and `-(a < b)`. Thanks

Comment: that part work for string and numbers as well for sorting. this approach should be fater than `localeCompare`, becaus it has not the locale for comparing.

Comment: If you have time, can you please explain with an example. Thanks.

Comment: there is no magic behind, it just takes the result of the comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var accounts = ["1111 12345678, Account1", 
              "2222 12345678, Account2", 
              "11345678, Account3", 
              "12345678, Account4", 
              "3333 12345678, Account5"];


function compare(a, b) {
  var aArr = a.split(' ');
  var bArr = b.split(' ');
  if (aArr.length > 2 && bArr.length > 2) {
    return aArr[2] > bArr[2];
  } else if (aArr.length > 2) {
    return -1;
  }  else if (bArr.length > 2) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return aArr[1] > bArr[1];
  }
}

console.log(accounts.sort(compare))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all items that contains > 2 spaces. Sort this array.
2. Get all items that contains === 2 spaces.

```js
let arr = ["3333 12345678, Account5","1111 12345678, Account1", 
              "2222 12345678, Account2", 
              "11345678, Account3", 
              "12345678, Account4", 
              ];
              
              
let arr1 = arr.filter((a) => {
  return a.split(' ').length > 2;
});

let sortedArr = arr1.sort();

let appendArr = arr.filter((a) => {
  return a.split(' ').length === 2;
});

sortedArr = [...sortedArr, ...appendArr];

console.log(sortedArr);
```